# how can I get innerHTML from a backdraftjs element?

Tags: javascript, backdraftjs

```
const foo = e.div('two cheeseburgers and an order of fries');
```

I would like to get the innerHTML of foo.

```
foo.innerHTML; // nope
foo.bdDom.root; // not this either
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured this out right after I posted...

```
const foo = e.div('two cheeseburgers and an order of fries');

const bar = render(foo);

console.log('innerHTML is ', bar.bdDom.root.innerHTML);
```

...seems to work. An element that isn't rendered HAS NO html.